# Get original path of user's filesystem of an uploaded media

Tags: media, filesystem

Is it possible within wordpress to retrieve the original upload path of a media?
For example, the user uploaded from **C:\pictures\holidays2014\image1.jpg**. I want **this** path, not the created path after the upload.

Edit: Rephrased the question.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: I believe that OP means php basically or a wordpress method.

Comment: I want to retrieve the string of the path and use the names of the folders. But I am not sure if the browser of the user gives this information or just send the files.

Comment: Ah, path on _client_ computer. I am pretty sure this is impossible with normal upload process.

Answer (score 0):

[`get_attached_file()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_attached_file/) can do this, given you know attachment ID for input.

Comment: Question was updated. OP accepted my rephrase.